# Locate indices where as.Date fails / not in standard format

Tags: r, coercion

I have a character column of dates that I'd like to coerce to Date class:

```
df$x <- as.Date(df$x)

# Error in charToDate(x)
#   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Fine, I'm familiar with this error. I've got something like `""` or `90-Smarch-13"` in my column. The problem is that `head(df$x)` looks fine, with normal dates `2013-11-04`, so it's not a global problem with my column, but a problem with just a few rows.

My question is:

1. Can I find out how many rows aren't in this standard unambiguous format?
2. Can I locate the indices (with a view to inspecting them or dropping them)?

My thoughts:

1. Use `try`:

`for (i in 1:nrow(df)) try(as.Date$x[i]) # very slow, doesn't finish for 1M rows`

1. Try to guess what the problem is using `nchar`

`head(df[nchar(df$x) != 10 & !is.na(df$x), ]$x)`

Are there any more systematic methods?

Comment: Can you show us `head(df$x)`? `as.Date.character` throws that error when the first non-NA entry is not of the format `"%Y-%m-%d"` or `"%Y/%m/%d"`.

Comment: `head(df$x)` (`NA`s removed) is just `"2013-11-04 00:00:00" "2013-11-04 00:00:00" "2013-11-04 00:00:00" "2013-11-04 00:00:00" "2013-11-04 00:00:00" "2013-11-04 00:00:00" ` most of the dates are unambiguous, but finding the ones that aren't is the challenge.

Comment: That seems strange. `as.Date(c("2013-11-04 00:00:00","2013-12-42 1100:22","ddd"))` returns `"2013-11-04" NA  NA` as expected. I suspect something else is going on, but I can't reproduce it with the data you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` package, for example:

```
dates.toparse <- c("2013-11-04","" ,"90-Smarch-13","2012-05-04")
 ## parse dates , I give the correct format here %Y-%m-%d
(dates.parsed <- parse_date_time(dates.toparse,orders="Y-m-d"))
[1] "2013-11-04 UTC" NA               NA               "2012-05-04 UTC"
 ## to locate bad foarmatted elements
 dates.toparse[is.na(dates.parsed)]
[1] ""             "90-Smarch-13"
## or by indices
which(is.na(dates.parsed))
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I had to slightly modify your code as the majority of this column were `NA`. (I had to remove `NA` entries in response.)